# JSON Python Evaluation

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Json:

```
{
  "Herausgeber": "Xema",
  "Nummer": "1234-5678-9012-3456",
  "Deckung": 2e+6,
  "Waehrung": "EURO",
  "Inhaber": {
    "Name": "Mustermann",
    "Vorname": "Max",
    "maennlich": true,
    "Hobbys": [ "Reiten", "Golfen", "Lesen" ],
    "Alter": 42,
    "Kinder": [],
    "Partner": null
  }
}
```

Is there a quick way to evaluate this like in javascript, so you can have a python 2.7 object by simple evaluating a full textfile in JSON-Format?

So you have something like:

```
file = read('text.json')
obj = eval(file)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `eval()`; JSON is not Python even if they look a lot alike. Use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse it:

```
import json

with open('text.json') as f:
    obj = json.load(f)
```

This uses [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) to load the JSON data from an open file object. If you have a string containing the JSON data use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) (note the `s`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
eval("""{
  "Herausgeber": "Xema",
  "Nummer": "1234-5678-9012-3456",
  "Deckung": 2e+6,
  "Waehrung": "EURO",
  "Inhaber": {
    "Name": "Mustermann",
    "Vorname": "Max",
    "maennlich": true,
    "Hobbys": [ "Reiten", "Golfen", "Lesen" ],
    "Alter": 42,
    "Kinder": [],
    "Partner": null
  }
}""")
```

The above code raised an error:

> NameError: name 'true' is not defined

So, because the true keyword is not acceptable in python, you'd better not to do this.

---

#### Do this istead:

```
import json

obj = json.loads("""{
      "Herausgeber": "Xema",
      "Nummer": "1234-5678-9012-3456",
      "Deckung": 2e+6,
      "Waehrung": "EURO",
      "Inhaber": {
        "Name": "Mustermann",
        "Vorname": "Max",
        "maennlich": true,
        "Hobbys": [ "Reiten", "Golfen", "Lesen" ],
        "Alter": 42,
        "Kinder": [],
        "Partner": null
      }
    }""")

print(obj)
```

Comment: The "you can try" part is bad advice, and not just because "true" isn't accepted by python. This data is not python, treating it as such is a coding error. It's no different than if you tried to call `eval` on XML or a recipe or song lyrics.

Answer (score -1):

You can use python 3.0 eval function which essentially converts the json string into a python dictionary. However, it is not considered as a good practice as people can inject malicious code which the eval statement runs as python code. If you still want to try it works something like this:

```
s = "{'review': 4.0,'beer/style': 'American Double / Imperial IPA'}"
y = eval(s)
type(y)
```

Comment: There are other good reasons not to`eval` json directly.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835672/468252 for some good discussions.